# jquery flot chart highlight dot when near point

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am making a chart using jQuery flot (plot)

https://jsfiddle.net/5gtqwkjg/2/

```
var updateLegendTimeout = null;
var latestPosition = null;

function updateLegend() {

    updateLegendTimeout = null;

    var pos = latestPosition;

    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    if (pos.x < axes.xaxis.min || pos.x > axes.xaxis.max || pos.y < axes.yaxis.min || pos.y > axes.yaxis.max) {
        return;
    }

    /*
            var o = plot.pointOffset({ x: pos.x, y: -1.25 });
            var ctx = plot.getCanvas().getContext("2d");

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(o.left, o.top);
            o.top = 0;
            ctx.lineTo(o.left, o.top);
            ctx.stroke();
            */

    var i, j, dataset = plot.getData();
    var halfDist = (dataset[0].data[1][0] - dataset[0].data[0][0]) / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {

        var series = dataset[i];

        // Find the nearest points, x-wise

        for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j) {
            if (series.data[j][0] - halfDist > pos.x) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Now Interpolate

        var y,
        p1 = series.data[j - 1],
            p2 = series.data[j];

        if (p1 == null) y = p2[1];
        else if (p2 == null) y = p1[1];
        else y = p1[1];

        legends.eq(i).text(series.label.replace(/=.*/, "= " + y.toFixed(2)));
        //dataset[i].highlightColor = "#abcdef";
        //plot.highlight(dataset[0].series, dataset[0].datapoint);
    }
}

$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    latestPosition = pos;
    if (!updateLegendTimeout) {
        updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend, 50);
    }
});
```

I want to add in a functionality that when the user moves the mouse along the x-axis the dot will highlight to indicate what point they are hovering nearest to. I already have the legend reflect the values but how would I highlight the dots?

EDIT: Very helpful answers guys! Here is the finished result if anyone is interested
https://jsfiddle.net/5gtqwkjg/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions provided by Flot.

> ***highlight(series, datapoint)***
>
> Highlight a specific datapoint in the data series. You can either
>   specify the actual objects, e.g. if you got them from a "plotclick"
>   event, or you can specify the indices, e.g. highlight(1, 3) to
>   highlight the fourth point in the second series (remember, zero-based
>   indexing).
>
> ***unhighlight(series, datapoint) or unhighlight()***
>
> Remove the highlighting of the point, same parameters as highlight.
>
> If you call unhighlight with no parameters, e.g. as
>   plot.unhighlight(), all current highlights are removed.

See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods for reference.

---

Applying that logic to your question, I **think** I managed to create the desired result you were looking for.

I first start by unhighlighting everything, just to make sure nothing slips past us when we **do** highlight points.

```
for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {

        plot.unhighlight(); // Unhighlight everything!

        var series = dataset[i];
```

Next up we go do the fun part, *highlight **all** the points!* (Just the ones we actually want to highlight)

In your "Find the nearest points, x-wise" loop I added another loop!

```
for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j) {    
    if (series.data[j][0] - halfDist > pos.x) { 
        for(a = 0; a < dataset.length; a++) {  // <-- The added loop

            // You might want to optimize the way this is done
            // The way you were storing the series data didn't seem to work like I..
            // ..wanted it do, so I had to iterate the dataset variable again.
            // The yellow line won't highlight if you change dataset[a] to series. 
            plot.highlight(dataset[a], series.data[j][0]);
        }

        break;
     }
 }
```

The result https://jsfiddle.net/qj3068zn/6/, for ease of use.

Do note, none of this is optimized. You're probably better off restructuring your code to provide a more general way to approach this and increase reusability and readability.

Comment: The values in the legend seem to be wrong in your fiddle, they were correct in the fiddle in the question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that one! I fixed it, it now shows the correct values. The  problem was how the `halfDist` variable was calculated and how the values were retrieved to be shown on the legend.

Comment: I'm not sure why you changed the `halfDist` in the first place. It works fine as it is (see my answer).

Comment: I kept getting x+1 when debugging and figured I would add the -1 to `halfDist` resulting in the correct x value. But, like you noticed, it generates incorrect legend values, so I had to remove -1 somewhere else aswell. Your approach keeps true to OP's original code and is a whole lot simpler.

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple - I was thinking that I had to pass in some object rather than just an 'id'. I wish I could give 2 correct answers but yours is a lot more in depth. Thank you sirs!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `highlight()` function like [Michel de Nijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677161/michel-de-nijs) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29534306/2610249), but a simpler version:

1) Put the `plot.unhighlight();` at the start of your `updateLegend` function (you might also want to rename that since it not longer only updates the legend).

2) Add `plot.highlight(i, j-1);` after your `for (j ...)` loop.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gtqwkjg/3/) for the code.